# Sketch a parametric function

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

We have a parametric function here and we want to obtain a rough sketch of it.
$$x(t)=t-\sin t\quad y(t)=1-\cos t$$

I found that $\frac{dx}{dt}=y$. But I don’t know how that will help me sketch the function. And of course, I tried to represent $t$ in terms of $y$ and substitute it back to $x(t)$. But that makes the whole thing even more complex. I need some help or hints.

Comment: The curve you are describing is the parametric equation of a cycloid. This is the shape of a curve traced by observing the motion of a point on a wheel undergoing pure rolling motion.

Comment: Yeah that is cycloid but I wonder how I can sketch it without the background knowledge?

Comment: Can you tabulate $(x,y)$ for $ t= (0,\pi/2, \pi,3 \pi/2 ,2\pi)$ and plot them along with some other in between  points? Sketch the arch. Now y=0 gives $x=0,2\pi, 4 \pi , ..$ So the same cycloidal arch repeats indefinitely either side. So copy the same sketches.

Comment: Tip: Write `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$, etc.